# Issue with "chaining" SQL commands

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

I am working with a postgreSQL database in VSCode via the SQL Tools extension. I have the following query, but it does not execute. I suspect the reason is because I am not "chaining" the queries properly.

```
-- @block create employee table
-- @conn myfirstconnection
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO test_table(
    first_name, 
    last_name
)
VALUES ('Samantha', 'Gray');
```

I receive the following error: `syntax error at or near "INSERT" at character 146`. If I were to separate the  commands and then run each separately, this error does not arise.

Ideally, I could execute the one query instead of having to first execute a `CREATE TABLE` and then executing an `INSERT`. Is there a proper terminology for doing this kind of chaining of queries?

Comment: Add a `;` after each command

Comment: You are not "chaining" statements. You simply have a single SQL script that happens to contain multiple statements (and each statement needs to be terminated with a `;`)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I didn't know if there was a terminology, but now I do.

Answer (score 2):

missing semicolon";" after create statement :

```
-- @block create employee table
-- @conn myfirstconnection
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50)
); --<-- here 
INSERT INTO test_table(
    first_name, 
    last_name
)
VALUES ('Samantha', 'Gray');
```

Comment: Oh I see. I thought the `;` was used at the end, but  I see that clearly it has to be at the end of each statement if they're to be chained together. As an aside, is it bad practice to chain together queries like I did or should they be separated?

Comment: no it's not bad practice, why it would be bad! in theory you can run as many as queries to be executed right after each other.

Comment: There is no such thing as "chained queries", they are just multiple queries ran at once.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the semicolon(;) after create table statement.

```
-- @block create employee table
-- @conn myfirstconnection
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO test_table(
    first_name, 
    last_name
)
VALUES ('Samantha', 'Gray');
```

Db-Fiddle:

```
 CREATE TABLE test_table(
     id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
     first_name VARCHAR(50),
     last_name VARCHAR(50)
 );
 
 INSERT INTO test_table(
     first_name, 
     last_name
 )
 VALUES ('Samantha', 'Gray');
```

Select query:

```
 select * from test_table;
```

Output:

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Samantha | Gray |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=69958a7baed2ae66b53ab1fe7dc2e57b)*

Comment: Did not know about DB-Fiddle, this is a good tool to know about!

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple queries at once but each query still need to be defined properly and especially ending with a `;`.

How to run multiple queries at once depends a lot on the way you run them but from VSCode I suppose you have to select both queries and click on some button (as opposed to not selecting the query or only selecting one).